# How can I turn off Toad auto correct of "FORM"?

Tags: toad

Toad automatically corrects `FORM` to `FROM` as I type. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Even in comments...super annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Toad you are using will determine the location of the option, but it's an auto replace string. In the most recent versions of Toad this is on the Editor|Auto Replace page in Options. In older versions of Toad it was on the Editor|Behavior page in Options, click the Auto Replace button. Remove any entries in there you do not like.

Comment: For my version it was burried in View > Toad Option > Editor > Auto Replace (button). I deleted the line for "Form" and now I'm all set. Thanks for the assist!